# Why is clear not working here?

Tags: java, javafx, event-handling

I have a problem with clearing a `TextArea` in Java.

```
Button gen = new Button("generate");
gen.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            textArea.clear();
            combination.init();
            setPassword();
            textArea.setText(password);
        }
    });
```

When the `Button` is clicked, the event handler puts the string "password" into the `TextArea`. It gets the string by doing this:

```
combination.init();
setPassword();
```

Then it puts the string into the `TextArea`:

```
textArea.setText(password);
```

If the `Button` is clicked again, a new string will be generated and put into the `TextArea`. But instead of clearing it beforehand, the new string just gets put after the last.

I tried solving it like this, but it seems just wrong and also doesn't work:

```
int i = textArea.getParagraphs().size();
if(i != 0) {
    textArea.clear();
}
```

So what am I doing wrong? Why doesn't it clear the `TextArea`?

Comment: the problem is not with the `textArea.clear();` method, it is useless anyways. May be `combination.init();` or  `setPassword();` method is causing the problem. can you post these methods ?

Comment: The problem is caused by code you haven't posted. Create a [MCVE].

Comment: Post the code of your methods `setPassword()` and `combination.init()`.

Comment: It seems you set a  `password ` in your textArea not a result of your method.Be sure that  `setPassword change your  `password `

Comment: Try System.out.println(password) ,to be sure that password is changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @DVarga says ,you don't need `clear()` method when you use `setText()` ,because the last one it clear previous text before adding new value.

> If the Button is clicked again, a new string will be generated and put
>   into the TextArea.

The problem come from `setPassword()`,I guess when you generate a new value you did not put it in password ,and you thought the problem from `clear()`,because you added the password in TextArea not a result if your method setPassword().

This example explain more your problem :

```
    gen.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {

            // combination.init();
            String generated = setPassword();
            area.setText(generated);

        }

    });
```

And this is method generate a string each clicked :

```
private String setPassword() {
        byte[] array = new byte[7]; // length is bounded by 7
        new Random().nextBytes(array);
        String generatedString = new String(array, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        return generatedString;
    }
```

Or by changing the value of password in `setPassowrd()` like this :

```
gen.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {

                // combination.init();
                setPassword();
                area.setText(password);

            }

        });
    }

    private void setPassword() {
        byte[] array = new byte[7]; // length is bounded by 7
        new Random().nextBytes(array);
        String generatedString = new String(array, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        password = generatedString;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As `textArea.setText(password);` will also "clear" the text, the problem is not with the `clear` method (however it is useless).

The problem must come from (one of) these methods

```
combination.init();
setPassword();
```

where you most probably append the new text to the previous text rather than overwrite it (the `password` member variable contains the wrong text already).

If you post the mentioned methods, the root problem could be found here, or based on this you can find the bug yourself.

Comment: `combination.init();` just starts the process of generating a random String (I don't want to bother you with all the code). And `set.password();` overwrites the existing String with the newly generated one. I checked that this is working. It seems to somehow append the Strings to one another inside the event handler method.

Comment: As `textArea.setText(password);` is the last statement in the handler, it is impossible that the problem is caused by the handler - you can 100% sure. So 1) the variable "password" contains the corrupted text or 2) you have another handler.